How to change the colour of a boolean (background green) in a html calendar using Jupyter?
I currently have a working calendar, which pulls information from a JSON file, and displays key information on the established day. Everything it pulls is a string except for a section I have called 'run', which is a boolean. I am looking for how to edit the background to show green if it is turned to true.
I am pretty new to html, mostly reiterating a colleagues code. I have attempted to set the colour using python colour schemes such as
if w['run'] == True
    return(\033[0;30;42mTrue \033[0m)

I have this at the moment after bringing in my json and building the calendar shape:
for week in month_days:
        calendar_html+="<tr>"
        for day in week:
            if day == 0:
                calendar_html+="<td>"
            else:
                calendar_html+="<td><p class= 'daynumber'><b>%s</b></p><br>" % (day)
                events_list =[]
                for i in data_json:
                    for w in data_json[i]['retests']:
                        if w['retest_date'] == "%s-%s-%s" % (year,str(month).zfill(2),str(day).zfill(2)):
                            if not w['comment']:
                                if w['run'] == True:
                                    calendar_html+= "<b>1:</b> %s <br><br><b>2:</b> %s<br><b>3:</b> %s <br><b>4:</b> %s (%s) <br><br><b>Run?</b> %r <br><hr width= 98%%>" % (data_json[i]['1'],data_json[i]['2'],len(data_json[i]['list']),w['3'],w['4'],w['run'])

I have attempted putting the background colour within the calendar_html around the %r or around the w['run'] as well but I am unsure whether any of this is close to correct. Any help will be appreciated.

Trying to help with HTML (I'm not a Python coder) so... (1) Fastest thing to try for a result is: In your last line with calender_html=+ there you could replace %r with <text style=\"background-color: rgb(0, 255, 0);\"> %r </text>. Is that now getting closer to your expectations? (2) It's not clear where you put the colour part in your variable, when you say "I have attempted putting the background colour within the calendar_html around the %r  ... but I am unsure whether any of this is close to correct".  Make that code part obvious if you want it fixed by others.

@VC.One Thanks for the reply! I had attempted something like \033[0;30;42m %r \033[0m but having tried what you recommended, I have gotten the perfect result, so thank you. I can adapt that to exactly what I need.
I am also now looking to alter certain background colours for cells. Is there a website you recommend that shows what you put in as I haven't found the application of the kind of notation you used in my searching? It would just be having the calendar_html=+ iteration be a certain background colour after some IF statements.
